# How to detection of the boundary of the left ventricle

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

[image]How to detection of the boundary of the left ventricle from MR images, the crucial step is to determine the region of interest (ROI) or the center point (CP) of the left ventricle.

I just want to show this marker over the Left ventricle of heart of MR Dicom Image

Comment: You really need to be much, much more specific about the problem and show some actual images. In its current form, your question can not be answered, and broadly covers two entire fields or research.

Comment: @Maurits I update the post, also i want to display above such Red marker , Green marker over MR Dicom file.